# XMLGregorianCalendar to DateTime Java

Tags: java, datetime, jodatime

When I get the DateTime from XML it is XMLGregorianCalendar:

```
2010-12-02T10:00:00
```

Than I make a String that looks like this:

```
2010-12-02 10:00:00
```

But when I try to parse it into a workable DateTime (joda.datetime) via:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
DateTime dt = formatter.parseDateTime("2010-12-02 10:00:00");
```

It returns this:

```
2010-12-02T10:00:00.000+01:00
```

Where I want it to look like the String but than as DateTime so I can use it....

Comment: Your question is not clear, you are parsing a formatted date, and expecting the same. Then why you need a formatter, you can use the input directly..?

Comment: I do not understand what you want to do. You want to parse a date as a String into a joda DateTime object?

Comment: Yes, my input is XMLGregorianCalendar which looks like: 2010-12-02T10:00:00, eventually I want to get to a DateTime which looks like 2010-12-02 10:00:00

Comment: DateTime is a class which has its own `toString` method, the so the object will return a string a representation as given by teh toString method.

Comment: @Luc I think you have already converted the string to datetime object what else do you intend to do?

Comment: I'd like to have the DateTime format without millis, timezone and the "T"

Comment: @Luc then you need to use a formatter to control the output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the date string you're getting back is basically `dt.toString()`

You need to format the date using the formatter you have created, otherwise the format bares no relevance. Try this:

```
System.out.println(formatter.print(dt));
```

When you set the date using the formatter it purely uses the format you've defined to parse the string... this does not have any effect on the DateTime object so you still need to use your formatter when converting it back to a string

Comment: I do not want to convert it back to a string, i want the DateTime to have the format I can use

Comment: @Luc I think you're getting confused... the DateTime object is the format you 'can use'... when you write it out as a string then it'll display it in whatever format... it just isn't necessarily the same format you wrote it in

Answer (score 2):

The correct way to do this is using the `javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter` class which provides a way to create `java.util.Date` or `java.util.Calendar` from the String. You can then easily convert that to Joda time if you want to.

DatatypeConverter docs: http://jaxb.java.net/nonav/2.2.4/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter.html